# Adding textarea in formset - django

Tags: django, formset

I have a message form and a formset that includes questions for this message. I would like to add **textareas** in the form, instead of input field. - I am not sure why there are not many examples out there. The models looks like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    message_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    message_introduction = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message_title
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'messages'
```

and:

```
class Message_question(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name="message_questions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    message_question = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message_question
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'message_questions'
```

And the forms look like this:

class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = Message
fields = [
'message_title',
'message_introduction',

```
    ]
    labels = {
        'message_title': 'message_title',
        'message_introduction': 'message_introduction',

    }
    widgets = {'created_at': forms.HiddenInput(),'updated_at': forms.HiddenInput()}


class Message_questionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message_question
        fields = ['message_question',
                  ]
        widgets = {
            'message_question': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'formset-field', 'rows': 4}),
        }
```

Is it doable and if yes, what element of the above code shoudl I change please ?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [`forms.Textarea`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#textarea) widget. You're currently specifying a `forms.TextInput` widget.

Comment: YES!!!! thank you very much. Crazy something that straightforward, coming from Rails my focus point is elsewhere :(